# Issue with using OpenSlide

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openslide

I am new to C# and can't get OpenSlide to work. I need it to be able to read SVS files. Below is the code I have used. Is it possible I am missing something in a directory? My boss has used the same code and can get it to run without issue.
I am getting the following error:
OpenSlideNET.OpenSlideUnsupportedFormatException: 'Exception of type 'OpenSlideNET.OpenSlideUnsupportedFormatException' was thrown.'

```
using OpenSlideNET;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SVSCurrent1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           OpenSlideImage image = OpenSlideImage.Open("‪C:\\projects\\SVS\\JP2K-33003-1.svs");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your boss able to get this to work with the _exact same SVS file_?

Comment: Can you verify (with some other app) that the SVS file you're targeting exists, is not zero-length, and can be opened successfully with the other app?

Comment: Also, although you didn't say, I am assuming that it's failing when you click `button1`. If it's failing at some other point, please say where!

Comment: I've tried multiple SVS files from multiple sources. I haven't been able to open a svs file with any app on my computer. I also tried using openslide in Python. Yes it is failing after I click on button1, and shows the error on openslide line.

Comment: Huh. if no SVS files will open on your computer, in ANY app, the problem is almost certainly not an error with that code!

Comment: I assume you've looked at this link?  https://openslide.org/formats/aperio/. The stuff about detecting SVS files would probably apply. There's also this sample data:  http://openslide.cs.cmu.edu/download/openslide-testdata/Aperio/

Comment: That's why I was wondering if maybe I'm missing a crucial file in my directory.

Comment: Quite possibly. You've used other apps, not based on OpenSlide, to try to open the SVS files?

Comment: One thing you CAN try, within .NET, is to catch that format exception and print out (or, in debug, inspect) the Exception object, and see if there's an inner exception. Sometimes a general exception will be used to wrap a specific, OS-level exception. You may also find something logged in the Output window of VS.

Comment: There's a line on this page: https://github.com/yigolden/OpenSlideNET:  "To use it on Windows, make sure that libopenslide-0.dll and its dependencies are on the DLL Search Path (eg. the PATH environment variable)."

Comment: The issue was with copy and pasting my file path location. When I manually wrote out the location, I was able to run the application. I can't figure out why it was a issue because even when I pasted both lines into Notepad++ and told it to show hidden characters, both lines looked identical.

Comment: Wow!  I'm glad you were able to fix the problem!